# Problems with variables within new command for boldface, coloring, and centering text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting

I am trying to type a new command that centers, boldfaces, and colors some text red. Here's what I have at the moment by tinkering and looking at some code I already had:

```
\newcommand{\rub}{\large\bfseries\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont\color{red}\filcenter}
```

I made up the new command `\rub` and so far **everything** is working except that the text inside the curly brackets is not centered. How can I go about fixing by new command to make it centered?

I did try the following:

```
{\newcommand{\rub}{\large\bfseries\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont\color{red}\filcenter}{}{0em}{#1}
```

but got the error:

```
You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode. ...\selectfont\color{red}\filcenter}{}{0em}{#
```

and am not quite certain as to what that means.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm,right=2.00cm,top=1.50cm,bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}

\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\fontfamily{uncl}\selectfont\filcenter}{}{0em}{#1}

\titleformat{\section}         {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont\color{red}\filcenter}{}{0em}{#1}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\filcenter}{}{0em}{#1}

\newcommand{\scrip}{\Large\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont{}}

\newcommand{\rub}        {\large\bfseries\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont\color{red}\filcenter}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Sunday after Pentecost -- Sunday of All Saints}

\section{GREAT VESPERS}

\subsection{The Reading from the Wisdom of Solomon.\\
(5:15-6:3a)}

\scrip{15 But
the righteous live for evermore; their reward also is with the
Lord, and the care of them is with the most High. 16 Therefore shall they ...  ... and ill dealing shall overthrow the
stones of the mighty.

{\rub{CHAPTER 6}}

1 Hear therefore, O ye kings, and understand; learn, ye that be judges
of the ends of the earth. 2 Give ear, ye that rule the people, and glory in the
multitude of nations. 3a For power is given to you of the Lord, and sovereignty
from the Highest.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's rather hard guessing *how* you're using `\rub`.

Comment: @egreg I really just need to use it to apply all those attributes (boldface, text color red, that specific font, centering, and that font size) to text that will be between 2 larger bodies of text. Sort of as a header - kind of like a chapter header but not exactly as the document already has a chapter header as well as section and subsection headers. I suppose that a modified subsubsection header "could" fulfill the role here. But I am not certain?

Comment: What goes in the empty braces `...\filcenter}{(here)}{0em}...`?

Comment: This doesn't clarify the problem at all.

Comment: @egreg I'm sorry. What information is it that I need to provide because from my perspective I am not sure what you need to know here or what you are asking.

Comment: A Minimum Working Example is usually a good start, is it not?

Comment: You didn't add [1] in your second macro definition, so tex wasn't prepared to handle #1. See my answer, which I think does what you want.

Comment: Do you use `titlesec`?

Comment: @JefferyShivers When I tried adding [1] in the curly braces, I still got the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the argument supplied to `\rub` and set it inside a centred box that has the width of `\linewidth`:

```
\newcommand{\rub}[1]{\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\large\bfseries\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont\color{red}#1}}
```

Here is a minimal example (*without* the font changes, as it's not part of the discussion):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0em}{#1}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{red}\filcenter}{}{0em}{#1}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0em}{#1}

\newcommand{\scrip}[1]{{\Large #1}}

\newcommand{\rub}[1]{\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\large\bfseries\color{red}#1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Sunday after Pentecost -- Sunday of All Saints}

\section{GREAT VESPERS}

\subsection{The Reading from the Wisdom of Solomon.\\
(5:15-6:3a)}

\scrip{15 But the righteous live for evermore; their reward also is with the
Lord, and the care of them is with the most High. 16 Therefore shall they \ldots
and ill dealing shall overthrow the stones of the mighty.

\rub{CHAPTER 6}

1 Hear therefore, O ye kings, and understand; learn, ye that be judges
of the ends of the earth. 2 Give ear, ye that rule the people, and glory in the
multitude of nations. 3a For power is given to you of the Lord, and sovereignty
from the Highest.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Only one problem with that is that since I am using a highly italic font for the body text of the scripture readings, and I want to have "Chapter 6" in ALL CAPS, it comes out looking bad (at least for my eyes) with all caps in that italic caligraphic font,

Comment: Never mind for some reason all of what you had typed did not copy for me. Upon trying it the second time it worked fine! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: When did Tex.SX start being evangelic?

Answer (score 2):

```
\newcommand*\rub[1]
  {\begin{center}\large\bfseries\color{red}\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont#1\end{center}}

...

\rub{This text will be centered, boldfaced, colored red and with font `pbk'}
```

But since you did not say what you are going to use it for, we don't know if there is a more precise and correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\rub}{\large\bfseries\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont\color{red}\filcenter}

\rub Mytext

\end{document}
```

If you want to use as `\rub{only inside here will be affected}`, then:

```
\newcommand{\rub}[1]{\large\bfseries\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont\color{red}\filcenter{#1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which does not use `center` environment, which adds unnecessary  vertical space.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\rub}[1]{%
    \par\hfil{%
    \centering%
    \large%
    \bfseries%
    \fontfamily{pbk}%
    \selectfont%
    \color{red}%
    #1%
    }\hfil\par}
\begin{document}%
\rub{Short text}%
\lipsum[1]
\rub{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```